# is Indexing required in Timescaledb?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have imported more than 3 billion rows in timescaledb. Is there any need for indexing the data to pull out fast like in mysql ?

Comment: That depends on the queries you use. Note that the TimescaleDB extension does not add any speed to queries.

Comment: There's some decent notes in the Timescale docs about indexing https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/schema-management/indexing/